# How to determine whether a large number is prime

Tags: number-theory

In the introduction part of "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves", it was mentioned that there are very quick ways to check that an integer is itself a prime although it is virtually impossible to perform a factorization. And I'm curious how to quickly determine whether a large number is prime.

Comment: [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) is a polynomial-time algorithm. There are effectively faster methods, but on the theoretical aspect I think it's considered the fastest.

Comment: Seems like a good place to start: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: My favorite is the APR-Test (Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely-Test), but the simple strong pseudoprime test is already very powerful, but the result "prime" is not absolutely surely true.

Comment: The Elliptic curve method (ECM) is both useful to prove the primality of a number and finding prime factors upto $30-40$ digits, with much effort (or much good luck) even upto $50-60$ digit-factors.

Answer (score 2):

Primality is a much easier problem than factorization in practice, and the best known complexity results are better as well.

As rywit mentioned, the Wikipedia page has lots of good information.

From a practical point of view, [this graph](http://probableprime.org/images/primality-times.png) gives an examples of times for single threaded implementations of a few primality proof methods on a 4770K, as well as BPSW, a fast probable prime test.  It doesn't cross 1 second for average time to prove primality on random primes until ~250 digits using either APR-CL or ECPP.  BPSW is still under 0.2 seconds at 2000 digits, albeit a probable prime test.  The time for BPSW is 2.5-3x the cost of a single Miller-Rabin test.

Easiest way to test:  use Pari/GP and its `ispseudoprime` function for probable prime test (using AES BPSW) or `isprime` function for an APR-CL proof.  Other useful software includes OpenPFGW, Primo, ecpp-dj, mpz_aprcl, Wolfram Alpha, and others.

Algorithms include:

- various methods for special forms (e.g. Mersenne, Proth, 2^n +/- 1, etc.).  Some software with at least one of these include OpenPFGW, prime95, LLR, Perl/ntheory, and more.
- ECPP.  The fastest method in common use for large inputs.  Primo is the standard, especially for >2k digits.  There are a couple others you can find, including my ecpp-dj open source software.  These give certificates of primality, which is a big advantage over other methods.  This means anyone can independently and quickly verify that it passes all the necessary tests.
- APR-CL.  Pari/GP, mpz_aprcl, and alpertron are some implementations.
- BLS75 methods.  From the seminal 1975 paper, this shows numerous ways to prove primality based on partial factoring.  Pocklington's test from 1914 is a simple form of this type of test.
- AKS.  Landmark theoretical result.  Quite slow in practice, so isn't normally used.  IMO the probability of a programming error in an AKS implementation is higher than the chances a composite will pass a well designed and implemented probable prime test.
- Trial division.  Doesn't scale.
- Probable prime tests, such as BPSW and running random-base Miller-Rabin tests.  These aren't proofs, but done well they're good enough for almost all purposes, and they're very fast.    Most proof code starts with a probable prime test of some sort so it can quickly give an answer for almost every composite input.