# Carmichael Number on random number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am making a calculator which have to find out the given number is prime or not.
I found Sieve of Eratosthenes, which was a very **memory-eating way**
and some probable ways to find out if the given number is prime


**The Problem is this**
Most of the probable primality test cannot check the **Strong Pseudoprimes**
So I want to Double check if the given number is Carmichael Number. If it is, however it passes the primality test, it will be an composite number.


I really believe doing the probable primary test and checking Carmichael Number can speed up calculations. but I don't know how. please help me.




In short, **How can I found out the given number is Carmichael number**

Thank you

Comment: How large are you expecting the inputs to be? You might be able to get by with a list of the first thousand primes stored in memory.

Comment: You can verify that you have a Carmichael number with 
[Korselt's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Korselt.27s_criterion),
but this assumes factorization, which is for large numbers much more time-consuming than doing a sequence of strong-probable prime test like Miller-Rabin.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks Hmm...I am working on a Calculator Engine, so I don't now How big will be.

Comment: @gammatester I dont want to do factorization way because using it will be heavy. (Well, if there is light factorization algorithm than I can use that and don't ask about this but...) Is there are some way?

Comment: There is no light-factorization, but you can (and should) trial-divide your candidate up to a certain limit. If you are working on a calculator engine, I strongly advise to implement strong-probabale prime tests (incl. Miller-Rabin) and 
[BPSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test)
for large numbers (which has no false positives up to 2^64). There are a lot of Q/A here, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407103/how-to-determine-whether-a-large-number-is-prime/1408730#1408730

Comment: @gammatester Thank you. I will Apply to my Engine.